# Making an image of a SD with a partition smaller than the SD size

Tags: image, image-size

I have a 16Gb SD where I have a 2Gb partition which I use with a Raspberry Pi. I want to make an image of the SD but only of the partitioned space. I tried to do it with the "Win 32 Disk Imager" but the result is a 16Gb file, so also the non allocated space is copy into the file.

Is there any way to copy only the partitioned space on the image, maybe using Linux utilities? Or is it possible to edit the image file an delete the extra "empty" space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you by any chance have an external hard drive you could copy ALL the contents of the Raspberry Pi partition including hidden and operating system files...Then you could delete the partition and merge it with your current partition using a tool like: [Minitool Partition Wizard.](http://download.cnet.com/MiniTool-Partition-Wizard-Home-Edition/3000-2094_4-10962200.html)

Then you could create a system image of your 14GB HDD and copy it to the External HDD and then at last remake the partitions using a partition tool and copy back the contents of your Rasberry Pi partition into the new partition you would have made. Now I do not know what effect this has on registry files so I would try this with caution. I do not know if there are registry files tied to the partition that you cannot copy or see so I would also make a registry backup... Idk if you want to try this but maybe this will help you out.